# How do I use AuthorizationCodeCredential with GraphServiceClient?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I know the authorization code can be obtained through the authorization redirection, and this has been done.

I have created the GraphServiceClient with the sample code in this [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=java#tabpanel_1_java), and it really does work, but it only works for the first API request, an error of No access token found occurred for any subsequence requests.

```java
final String clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
final String tenantId = "YOUR_TENANT_ID"; // or "common" for multi-tenant apps
final String clientSecret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";
final String authorizationCode = "AUTH_CODE_FROM_REDIRECT";
final String redirectUrl = "YOUR_REDIRECT_URI";
final List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("User.Read");

final AuthorizationCodeCredential credential = new AuthorizationCodeCredentialBuilder()
    .clientId(clientId).tenantId(tenantId).clientSecret(clientSecret)
    .authorizationCode(authorizationCode).redirectUrl(redirectUrl).build();

if (null == scopes || null == credential) {
    throw new Exception("Unexpected error");
}
final TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(
    scopes, credential);

final GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
    .authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient();
```

It looks like the access token was not cached when using AuthorizationCodeCredential.

Currently I'm trying to make the access token accessible to the whole Web App, although this is not the correct scenario that the authorization code designed for, but I have to because the Client Credential flow is not available for now.

My question is how to make the access token available to subsequence API requests via GraphServcieClient, and how to automatically get a new access token with refresh token?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AuthorizationCodeCredential` to authenticate and authorize a user, but it only provides a single access token. The `GraphServiceClient` is designed to handle token caching and token refreshing. To make the access token available to subsequent API requests via `GraphServiceClient`, you can create an instance of `GraphServiceClient` and pass it an instance of `TokenCredentialAuthProvider` as its authentication provider. The `TokenCredentialAuthProvider` will handle token caching and token refreshing. Attaching a code snippet as an example:

```
final String clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
final String tenantId = "YOUR_TENANT_ID"; 
// or "common" for multi-tenant apps 
final String clientSecret ="YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"; 
final String authorizationCode = "AUTH_CODE_FROM_REDIRECT";
final String redirectUrl = "YOUR_REDIRECT_URI";
final List scopes = Arrays.asList("User.Read"); 
final AuthorizationCodeCredential credential = new AuthorizationCodeCredentialBuilder().clientId(clientId).tenantId(tenantId).clientSecret(clientSecret).authorizationCode(authorizationCode).redirectUrl(redirectUrl).build();
if (null == scopes || null == credential)
{ throw new Exception("Unexpected error"); }
final TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider= new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes,credential);
// Create an instance of GraphServiceClient and pass in the TokenCredentialAuthProvider
final GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder() .authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient(); 
// Use the GraphServiceClient to make API requests
final User user = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get()
```

Find more info [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=java)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that there was a bug in the AuthorizationCodeCredential class of azure-identity sdk, it didn't properly retrieve the cached access token for confidential clients. This [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/36994) has now been fixed.